# I've downloaded a shapefile that should show counties in UK, but it has a marker as a symbol?

Tags: qgis

I've downloaded this file: http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/0b09996863af4b5db78058225bac5d1b_3

Yet I cannot get the shapes of counties, the symbol given by default is a marker. Can anyone help? I just want a layer showing counties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you downloaded, but if you hit the little arrow on the download button and select 'Shapefile', you sould get a layer showing counties. At least that's what I got.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For some reason, I can't see anything at all. It's loaded in layers however.

Comment: same for me, i got a polygon shapefile. Maybe a bad qgis display setting ? What kind of layer icon do u have in the layers panel ?

Comment: Have you checked if the coordinate reference system of your project is the same as the layers coordinate reference system?

Comment: I have a square with purple inside. What is CRS?

Comment: How do I check coordinate reference system of my project?

Comment: It is written in the lower right corner of the QGIS window

Comment: CRS matches for my layer and project

Comment: Make sure all 6 files are in the same folder. Then try Right Click --> Zoom On Layer.

Comment: Both SHP and KML work perfectly for me.  If you selected 'spreadsheet' from the options, it is just a table with no geometry - so you will see it in the layers but nothing on-screen.  I recommend doing a fresh download following blabath's directions (select either Shapefile or KML)

Comment: So ... what was the explanation ?